# Multinomial coefficient upper bound in proof of analyticity of solutions to PDEs

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to work my way through a proof of the real analyticity of solutions to elliptic PDEs in Bers and Schechter's *Partial Differential Equations*. At some point they claim they can bound derivatives of smooth solutions $u$ to $Lu=f$ in a controlled way. As far as I understand it, their argument boils down to obtaining the following bound:

$$|u D^qv|\leq |D^{q}(uv)|+ K \sum_{\substack{|q'+q''|= |q|\\q'\neq 0}} \binom{|q|}{|q'|}|D^{q'}u||D^{q''}v|,$$

where $q$ is some multiindex $q\in \mathbb{N}_0^n$ and $u,v\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions. Importantly, $K$ here is a constant that does not depend on $q$, $u$ or $v$.
Using the Leibnitz formula I can see that:

$$|u D^qv|\leq |D^{q}(uv)|+ \sum_{\substack{|q'+q''|= |q|\\q'\neq 0}} \binom{q}{q'}|D^{q'}u||D^{q''}v|,$$

but I am having trouble continuing from here. Is the bound above even correct? Is there a way of bounding a multinomial coefficient in terms of the corresponding binomial coefficient? I'm thinking along the lines of:

$$\binom{q}{q'}\leq K\binom{|q|}{|q'|},$$

at least for $q'\neq 0$.

Comment: All right, this was actually not hard. I stumbled upon the answer (despite looking for it before!) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722009/multinomial-coefficient-estimate?rq=1